# Bios Error Following Kernel Update

Tags: kernel, bios

I recently had to reboot due to a kernel update and I noticed  the following error:

[image]

I don't know if the error is caused by the update or whether hard drive is possibly going bad.

All suggestions for diagnosing resolving this error are appreciated.

Comment: Everything is OK. It is probably because of a new kernel.

Comment: Yup... great answer.. was very much worried.  Started checking the backups :-) .. @Pilot6 thx..

Comment: New kernel started reporting these problems with poor UEFI. I don't see it on any device.